# Using a Stack within a PositionedTransition

Tags: flutter

I am trying to animate some widgets using a PositionedTransition and getting some odd behaviour. The child of the PositionedTransition is a Stack as well. I created a sample to compare behaviour of the simple Positioned widget and the PositionedTransition widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Animation<RelativeRect> transition = RelativeRectTween(
            begin: RelativeRect.fromSize(
                Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100), Size(100, 100)),
            end: RelativeRect.fromSize(
                Rect.fromLTWH(50, 50, 100, 100), Size(100, 100)))
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));

    return Stack(children: [
      PositionedTransition(rect: transition, child: getCircles()),
      Positioned(top: 50, right: 50, child: getCircles())
    ]);
  }
```

I would expect both widgets to look the same, although one static and the other is animated. But this is not the case if you look at this DartPad:
[Full working DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/f6915eb3fb052d734183e7157d4e1e39)

Anyone any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In this case, you can use `Stack` wrap `Center` and `Positioned` 
code snippet

```
Stack(children: [
      ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100),
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "circle",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
    );
    _controller.duration = Duration(seconds: 2);
    _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _controller.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Animation<RelativeRect> transition = RelativeRectTween(
            begin: RelativeRect.fromSize(
                Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100), Size(100, 100)),
            end: RelativeRect.fromSize(
                Rect.fromLTWH(50, 50, 100, 100), Size(100, 100)))
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));

    return Stack(children: [
      PositionedTransition(rect: transition, child: getCircles()),
      Positioned(top: 50, right: 50, child: getCircles())
    ]);
  }

  Widget getCircles() {
    return Stack(children: [
      ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100),
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "circle",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 40, maxHeight: 40),
                        child: DecoratedBox(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            "mini",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                        ))),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chunhunghan! This is what I was aiming for. Can you explain why my positioning of the mini circle causes this behaviour?

Comment: For PositionedTransition, first Stack of getCircles reference coordinate is whole screen. second Stack of getCircles  reference coordinate is ConstrainedBox. When you put Positioned in first Stack, mini Text is actually in bottom left of screen.